# Should Auth-Only Credit Card Transactions be Stored Separately from Auth-Capture Transactions in a Database?

Tags: database-design, payment, credit-card, authorize.net

### Background

I've built an e-commerce application that connects to Authorize.net's payment gateway.  Administrators can process credit cards in the following ways:

1. "Capture" transaction where the admin charges the customer's credit card immediately.
2. "Auth-Only" transaction where the admin authorizes $X from the credit card and then actually captures the amount later (see number 3 below)
3. "Prior-Auth-Capture" transaction where the admin captures an amount equal to or less than an amount previously captured from an "Auth-Only" transaction.

This question pertains to how these types of transactions should be stored in a database.  I have the following schema in my "Payments" table:

[image: payments table schema]

When a new payment is made, I store information about the payment method in the *PaymentAmount* field (e.g. Credit Card, Check, Cash).

If the PaymentType is "Credit Card" I store the *TransactionType* (e.g. Capture, Auth-Only, Prior-Auth-Capture").

*PaymentAmount* column holds the amount of the payment (if TransactionType is "capture" or "prior-auth-capture".  If the *TrandactionType* is "Auth-Only" I store the amount in the *AuthorizedAmount* column and keep track of the date the auth'd amount is good for in *AuthExpDate*.

Fields related to Authorize.net's transaction/reference data are stored in *ApprovalCode* and *TransactionID* columns.

### Back to the Question

Now that you have a little background, lets dig into the details of my question:  Should every transaction get it's own record in this table? Or should I update an existing transactions for "Auth-Only" transactions when I capture funds from them?

**Examples:**

1. New Record For Every Action:
   If a user makes an "auth-only" transaction I'll create a new record in the Payments table. If the user later runs a "prior-auth-capture" transaction on the initial transaction should I create a second row in the database or should I update the original transaction and add the amount captured to the PaymentAmount column?

   ```
   PaymentsID  TransactionID  PaymentType  PaymentAmount  AuthorizedAmount
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1          ABC123         Auth           0.00           100.00
       2          ABC123      Auth-Capture    100.00             0.00
   ```
2. Single row for each TransactionID and updating original transaction with each aut-capture.

   ```
   PaymentsID  TransactionID  PaymentType  PaymentAmount  AuthorizedAmount
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1          ABC123         Auth           100.00           100.00
   ```

Logically I can see arguments for both cases.  On one hand, if I create a new row with each transaction I can see a nice history of each hit against every "auth-only" transaction.  The downside is under circumstances where you make multiple "prior-auth-capture" transactions against a single "auth-only" transaction because to figure out how much you have left you have to write a slightly more complex query (joining the table to itself and grouping by TransactionID to get the sum of *PaymentAmount*).

If I create a single row for each TransactionID then I could easily update the PaymentAmount and calculate the amount remaining in the auth using a simple calculation (AuthorizedAmount - PaymentAmount = AuthorizedBalance).  This approach also makes things cleaner since the TransactionID, ApprovalCode, Payment Info, and pretty much everything else would remain the same so you have less redundant data in the table. Additionally, from a reporting point of view most users simply want to see a single row for each transaction for simplicity sake.

I'd love to hear your thoughts on the right way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the temptation to lose data/flexibility for the sake of simplicity; if you update the original row how would you determine the date/time of the auth & capture(s) independently?  How many captures were made?  What were the individual auth codes and other new values returned from the gateway API for each one?

If there are a lot of repeated fields with the same values shared between the different transaction types then normalise by moving them to a new table and storing an ID value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any right or wrong answer here (and so question should be closed as opinion based). However, I'd suggest a third way...

Use your 'updating row' model, but then add a new table for storing low level comms with Authorize.net. New table would capture payment id, date/time, auth type, auth value, etc.

That way you have something you can debug against, and also a history of dates/times/values per card and when they authed and charged.